# C# Command Delete : space file name

Tags: cmd, delete-file

"ents.dll" remove but "fast race.exe" not deleted. I think there are spaces. Help me please.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";


         startInfo.Arguments = "/C  del  ents.dll + fast race.exe";
         process.StartInfo = startInfo;
         process.Start();
```

Comment: I do not think that the command line `del` command uses a plus sign character to indicate multiple files.  Try just separating the file names with a space, like this: `startInfo.Arguments = "/C  del  ents.dll fast race.exe";`